# Cocomplete abelian category with enough injectives has exact coproducts

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, abelian-categories

In [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/289418/locally-presentable-abelian-categories-with-enough-injective-objects) post it is claimed that for any (cocomplete) abelian category with enough injectives, the coproduct functor is exact, that is for a family of short exact sequences $0 \to A_i \to B_i \to C_i \to 0$, also $0 \to \oplus_i A_i \to \oplus_i  B_i \to \oplus_i C_i \to 0$ is exact.
Since taking the coproduct is right exact, it suffices to see that for a family of monomorphisms $A_i \to B_i$ the morphism $\oplus_i A_i \to \oplus_i B_i$ is monic as well.

I thought about this a bit myself but as I’m not very familiar with abelian categories I did not get very far. Any hint, proof or reference for a proof would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category with enough injective objects, let $\mathcal{B}$ be the full subcategory of injective objects, and let $[\mathcal{B}, \textbf{Ab}]$ be the category of additive functors $\mathcal{B} \to \textbf{Ab}$.
Then the functor $\mathcal{A}^\textrm{op} \to [\mathcal{B}, \textbf{Ab}]$ defined by $A \mapsto \textrm{Hom} (A, -)$ is exact and fully faithful.
Moreover, it sends coproducts in $\mathcal{A}$ to products in $[\mathcal{B}, \textbf{Ab}]$.
But fully faithful functors are conservative, so this functor also reflects exactness, and $[\mathcal{B}, \textbf{Ab}]$ satisfies axiom AB4* (because $\textbf{Ab}$ does), hence $\mathcal{A}$ satisfies axiom AB4, as claimed.

---

There is also a somewhat more hands-on argument.
Coproducts are always right exact, so we only have to check that monomorphisms are preserved.

Let $A = \bigoplus_i A_i$, $B = \bigoplus_i B_i$, $C = \bigoplus_i C_i$.
We need to show that the induced $A \to B$ is a monomorphism.
Let $K = \ker (A \to B)$.
It suffices to show that $K \cong 0$.
Since $\mathcal{A}$ has enough injective objects, we may choose an injective object $J$ and a monomorphism $K \to J$.
We then have the following exact sequence:
$$\textrm{Hom} (B, J) \longrightarrow \textrm{Hom} (A, J) \longrightarrow \textrm{Hom} (K, J) \longrightarrow 0$$
On the other hand, for each $i$,
$$0 \longrightarrow \textrm{Hom} (C_i, J) \longrightarrow \textrm{Hom} (B_i, J) \longrightarrow \textrm{Hom} (A_i, J) \longrightarrow 0$$
is exact, so their product is also exact:
$$0 \longrightarrow \prod_i \textrm{Hom} (C_i, J) \longrightarrow \prod_i \textrm{Hom} (B_i, J) \longrightarrow \prod_i \textrm{Hom} (A_i, J) \longrightarrow 0$$
But $\textrm{Hom} (-, J)$ sends coproducts to products, so this implies $\textrm{Hom} (B, J) \to \textrm{Hom} (A, J)$ is an epimorphism, so $\textrm{Hom} (K, J) \cong 0$.
But we have a monomorphism $K \to J$, so this forces $K \cong 0$, as required.

Comment: Could one also use just the functors $\mathcal{B} \to \textbf{Ab}$ (this category also satisfies AB4*, right?), instead of the additive ones?

Comment: Yes, you could.